# How can I display TRUE/FALSE instead of 1/0 on laravel8 and Eloquent?

Tags: eloquent, boolean, laravel-8

Hi § I am creating a form using Laravel 8 and Eloquent.

Here is my form :

```
  <div class="mt-2">
    <label for="is-active"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="is-active" name='is_active">
  </div>
```

My migration file looks like :

```
public function up()
{            
Schema::table('newspapers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
});
}
```

In my Model, I have added this :

```
   protected $casts = [
    'is_active' => 'boolean',
];
```

In my Controller :

```
        $offer->is_active=$request->has('is_active');
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean display in the views, you can simply do this in your blade file:

```
{{ $offer->is_active ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' }}
```